# NSubstitute generic interface method setup throws NSubstitute.Exceptions.AmbiguousArgumentsException

Tags: generics, mocking, nsubstitute

I have the following interface definition

```
public interface INotificationRecipientsProvider<T, E>
    where T : EventBase<E>
    where E : class
{
    IList<string> NotificationRecipients(T notificastionEvent);
}

public abstract class EventBase<T> : IEvent<T>, INotification
{
    protected EventBase(T payload)
    {
        Payload = payload;
    }

    public abstract string Description { get; }

    public T Payload { get; }
}
```

I am trying to setup NotificationRecipients for T = CreatedEvent where:

```
public class CreatedEvent : EventBase<Source> { <abstract members implementation> }
```

This is the code for the setup

```
private void WithRecipients(IEnumerable<string> recipients) {
        _recipientProviderMock = Substitute.For<INotificationRecipientsProvider<CreatedEvent, Source>>();
        _recipientProviderMock
            .NotificationRecipients(Arg.Any<CreatedEvent>())
            .Returns(x => recipients?.ToList());
}
```

The above setup throws the following exception:

```
Test method [<TestMethodName>] threw exception:
NSubstitute.Exceptions.AmbiguousArgumentsException: Cannot determine argument specifications to use. Please use specifications for all arguments of the same type.
Method signature:
    NotificationRecipients(CreatedEvent)
Method arguments (possible arg matchers are indicated with '*'):
    NotificationRecipients(*<null>*)

All queued specifications:
    any Int32
    any CreatedEvent
Matched argument specifications:
    NotificationRecipients(???)
```

Unless I am missing something too obvious this seems to be a bug. I cannot even begin to imagine where Int32 comes from